# Android Navigation overflow menu item overlapping fargments

Tags: android, architecture, android-navigation, overflow-menu

I have been learning android navigation components from [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-navigation/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#1), after following through steps, at step 8 I came across to a weird bug.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Enter application.
2. From the overflow menu select Settings option. SettingsFragment is
   added and overflow menu is visible.
3. Again, select the Settings option from the overflow menu.
4. Press
       back.

see following screenshots
[mainfragment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRyRO.png) [settings Fragment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fbLr4.png)[after clicking settings fragment again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFDgO.png)

Comment: post the code where you are calling fragments to open...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue issued in [google issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/79407969#comment2) which was an internal bug for navigation aac, to fix add `navigationVersion = "1.0.0-alpha02"` in your `build.gradle` file